# Как разделить строку по 4 символа? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, split

имеется строка, состоящая из 0 и 1
как ее разделить по 4 символа? Возможно ли использовать split?

00001001001011100000100010   => 0000, 1001, 0010, 1110, 0000, 1000

Comment: Циклом пройдитесь с шагом 4 и все

Comment: А можно как-нибудь без цикла, регулярные выражения или еще что-нибудь?)

Comment: А чем вас цикл не устраивает?

Comment: Это длинно получится. А как это грамотно организовать циклом?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const sep = (xs, s) => xs.length ? [xs.slice(0, s), ...sep(xs.slice(s), s)] : []

console.log(sep("00001001001011100000100010", 4));
console.log(sep("00001001001011100000100010", 6));

console.log(sep([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], 4));
console.log(sep([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], 6));
```

Answer (score 2):

Тоже поучаствую, в этом празднике жизни

```js
const devi=(str, max=4, arr=[])=>{
    arr.push(str.substring(max*(arr.length), max*(arr.length+1)));
    return (arr.length < str.length / max | 0) ? devi(str, max, arr) : arr;
};

console.log('0000 1001 0010 1110 0000 1000');
console.log(devi('000010010010111000001000', 4));
```

Если последний элемент не `max`(4) символа:

```js
const devi=(str, max=4, arr=[])=>{
    arr.push(str.substring(max*(arr.length), max*(arr.length+1)));
    if(arr.length <= (str.length / max | 0))return devi(str, max, arr);
    else if(arr[arr.length-1].length < max)arr.pop();
    return arr;
};

console.log(0, '1110 1000 777');
console.log(1, devi('11101000', 4));
console.log(2, devi('111010007777', 4));
console.log(3, devi('11101000777', 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот и код склепал на коленке!

```js
let str = "00001001001011100000100010", currstr = "";
let array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
   currstr += str[i];
   // строка готова к выводу
   if (currstr.length == 4) {
      array.push(currstr);
      // обнуляем строку
      currstr = "";
   }
}
for (var i in array) {
   console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: И да если длина строки не делится нацело на 4, то код будёт работать некоректно! В условие ничего про это сказано не было)

Answer (score 0):

> имеется строка, состоящая из 0 и 1 как ее разделить по 4 символа?

Самый простой способ (имхо) это использовать [регулярные выражения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), вот так:

```js
const result = '00001001001011100000100010'.match(/[01]{4,4}/g)

console.log(result)
```

##### Что это за регулярное выражение?

`[01]` означает что выражение должно состоять из `0` или `1`. `{4,4}` означает что выражение должно быть длиной от 4, до 4 символов (то-есть только 4 символа). Также я добавил флаг `g` (global), чтобы получать все строки подходящие под это выражение, иначе мы бы получали только одну строку:

```js
const result = '00001001001011100000100010'.match(/[01]{4,4}/)

console.log(result)
```

Стоит также отметить, что данное выражение не будет находить подстроку, длина которой меньше 4, что может быть минусом для вас. Поэтому можно поменять часть выражения сделав его таким:

```js
const result = '00001001001011100000100010'.match(/[01]{1,4}/g)

console.log(result)
```

То-есть у нас получился поиск подстрок, состоящих из нулей и единиц с длиной от 1 до 4. Обратите внимание, что я не пишу 0, т.к. это поможет нам пропустить пустую строку которая останется, если искать подстроку с длиной минимум 0.

Если угодно, то можете использовать функцию:

```js
console.log(
  splitBinaryStr('00001001001011100000100010', 4)
) // Не требовать длины строки исключительно 4

console.log(
  splitBinaryStr('00001001001011100000100010', 4, true)
) // Требовать длину строки исключительно 4

function splitBinaryStr(str, requiredLength, forceLength) {
  const re = new RegExp(`[01]{${forceLength ? requiredLength : 1},${requiredLength}}`, 'g')

  return str.match(re)
}
```

> Возможно ли использовать split?

Нет, к сожалению нет, т.к. для метода `split` нужен разделитель по которому мы будем делить строку.

---

#### Бонусный способ

```js
const requiredLength = 4
const result = [...'00001001001011100000100010'].reduce((acc, elem) => {
  const lastItem = acc[acc.length - 1]

  if(!lastItem || lastItem.length > requiredLength - 1) {
    acc.push(elem)
  } else {
    acc[acc.length - 1] += elem
  }

  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Чтобы "отфильтровать" последнюю строку, при том случае если её длина меньше 4, то можно сделать так:

```js
const str = '00001001001011100000100010'
const requiredLength = 4

const result = [...str].reduce((acc, elem, index) => {
  const lastItem = acc[acc.length - 1]
  const indexesLeft = str.length - index + 1 // Добавляем единицу, т.к. индексы начинаются с нуля.

  if(indexesLeft < requiredLength) {
    return acc
  }

  if(!lastItem || lastItem.length > requiredLength - 1) {
    acc.push(elem)
  } else {
    acc[acc.length - 1] += elem
  }

  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```